# Edge/Vertex matrix from triangulation

Tags: matlab

I have to analyze some STL files with Matlab, and I import them successfully with an STL reader, but this function only returns vertices and faces (triangles).

This is [the STL reader](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22409-stl-file-reader?focused=5193625&tab=function) I am using, and [this is an example STL file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gppktdtkz668r5u/t4.stl?dl=0), generated by the `gmsh` tool with `gmsh -2 -format stl -bin t4.geo`. In case, the code for the STL function is at the end.

```
mesh = stlread("t4.stl");
```

Is there a function I can use to obtain the vertex/edge adjacency matrix from such a triangulation?

```
function [F,V,N] = stlbinary(M)

    F = [];
    V = [];
    N = [];

    if length(M) < 84
        error('MATLAB:stlread:incorrectFormat', ...
              'Incomplete header information in binary STL file.');
    end

    % Bytes 81-84 are an unsigned 32-bit integer specifying the number of faces
    % that follow.
    numFaces = typecast(M(81:84),'uint32');
    %numFaces = double(numFaces);
    if numFaces == 0
        warning('MATLAB:stlread:nodata','No data in STL file.');
        return
    end

    T = M(85:end);
    F = NaN(numFaces,3);
    V = NaN(3*numFaces,3);
    N = NaN(numFaces,3);

    numRead = 0;
    while numRead < numFaces
        % Each facet is 50 bytes
        %  - Three single precision values specifying the face normal vector
        %  - Three single precision values specifying the first vertex (XYZ)
        %  - Three single precision values specifying the second vertex (XYZ)
        %  - Three single precision values specifying the third vertex (XYZ)
        %  - Two unused bytes
        i1    = 50 * numRead + 1;
        i2    = i1 + 50 - 1;
        facet = T(i1:i2)';

        n  = typecast(facet(1:12),'single');
        v1 = typecast(facet(13:24),'single');
        v2 = typecast(facet(25:36),'single');
        v3 = typecast(facet(37:48),'single');

        n = double(n);
        v = double([v1; v2; v3]);

        % Figure out where to fit these new vertices, and the face, in the
        % larger F and V collections.        
        fInd  = numRead + 1;        
        vInd1 = 3 * (fInd - 1) + 1;
        vInd2 = vInd1 + 3 - 1;

        V(vInd1:vInd2,:) = v;
        F(fInd,:)        = vInd1:vInd2;
        N(fInd,:)        = n;

        numRead = numRead + 1;
    end

end
```

Comment: If you have faces you almost have the edges ... that's essentially one line of code, I'm sure you can do it if you try.

Comment: Should be easy, but the matrix I have, it seems, indexes once every triangle, so I'm puzzled. The fact is, the face matrix is just the list of numbers `1:nvertices` reshaped.

Comment: I don't understand how this code is related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your faces are in a n-by-3 array `F`:

```
% temporary array
T = [F(:,1) F(:,2) ; F(:,1) F(:,3) ; F(:,2) F(:,3)];

% get the edges
E = unique([min(T,[],2), max(T,[],2)],'rows');

% build the adjacency matrix
n = max(E(:,2));
A = sparse(E(:,1), E (:,2), ones(size(E,1),1), n, n);
A = A + A';
```

NB: sparse arrays are often useful for such adjacency matrix, especially in the large limit.

Best,

Comment: Thanks! I have a weird error though, it seems that `A` isn't square: when adding its symmetric, `A = A + A';`, I have this error `Error using  + Matrix dimensions must agree.`. In fact, the matrix has one dimension more than the other: `>> size(A) ans = 4616        4617`, how is this possible?

Comment: Yes this can happen depending on your data. I've edited my answer to take this into account. You simply want to precise the size of your adjacency matrix to the `sparse` function.

Comment: Thanks! I have one question. I tried with a very simple mesh, a 2x2 grid of squares, and this mesh has then 9 vertices and 8 faces, with 12 edges. The output matrix, however, is `adjacencymatrix: [24×24 double]`, while it should be a 12x9 (or 9x12 at most). Am I missing something?

Comment: @senseiwa Strange. The adjacency matrix should be 9-by-9, period. Can you provide the data? (list of vertices and faces)

Comment: Sure, it's in the question as a Dropbox link.